# How to get procedure data with select?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a Login screen, this screen will have the Username and Password. When the user clicks the login button will call the procedure that is in the database which in turn will have to return the data to see if that user exists or not.

I have a table with 3 fields inside this table, ID_USER (id primary key), NM_USER (user), PW_USER (password)

I am creating the procedure like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spPROC`(

    IN User VARCHAR(255),
    IN Pass VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM stu_accounts WHERE NM_USER = User AND PW_USER = MD5(Pass);

END
```

In PHP I'm doing this to get some value if possible, but I only have one type of blank return.

```
<?php
    define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('USER', 'root');
    define('PASS', 'root');
    define('DB', 'study_dev');

    $connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die ('Err Connection');
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, 'CALL spPROC(USER1, 1234);' or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error()));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
        echo  $row . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

What should I do to find User data in the database through the procedure, and then get the procedure data in PHP?

Comment: You're using a sproc just for fun/educational purposes?

Comment: I'm using for educational purposes

Comment: Presuming you were hardcoding proc args for testing, `USER1` should be quoted.... and technically so should `1234`.

Comment: USER1 is registered in the table, I'm trying to check if it exists in the field NM_USER with the correct password.